# POM Dependency for org.jboss.seam-jboss.seam-2.2.2.GA.jar

Tags: java, seam

I am unable to find the POM dependency entry for this jar - org.jboss.seam-jboss.seam-2.2.2.GA.jar

Would it be possible to help if anyone has come across this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Seam repository in your maven pom to get that dependency up and running.
You can find the steps required to do that at:

> http://seamframework.org/Seam3/MavenArtifacts

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JBoss maven 2 repository to your POM.

See the following page for details:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users

This page lists the versions of Seam:
http://seamframework.org/Seam2/Downloads